# Why does this statement doesnt require '&' symbol in scanf statement 'scanf( "%*[\n]%[^\n]",arr);'

Tags: c

Can somebody explain the meaning and the working of this statement of C

```
scanf( "%*[\n]%[^\n]",arr);
```

?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because post complete code.

Comment: A better question would be to tell us what you think it does, why you think that, and if the behavior of the program does not match your expectation, ask for specific help in a much more pointed fashion.

Comment: You need to look at how `arr` is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Let us break it down:

```
scanf( "%*[\n]%[^\n]",arr);
```

`%*[\n]` directs scanf to read any characters that **are** `'\n'`.  The `*` indicated to not save anything.  If it does not read at least 1 character, `scanf()` returns EOF.  Continue until `EOF` or until the next character is not a `'\n'`.

`%[^\n]` directs scanf to read any characters that are not `'\n'`.  These values are saved in the memory indicated by `arr`. This continues until the next character is `'\n'` or EOF occurs.  If no characters are read, 0 (or EOF) is returned.  If at least one was read, and no error, when done, a `\0` is appended and `scanf()` returns 1.

---

OP's code is not good code as there is no input limitation.  The following would be better.  Using `fgets()` is even better yet.

```
char arr[10];
scanf( "%*[\n]%9[^\n]",arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C, `scanf` is often used to fill `char` arrays. That is, `arr` is an array, declared like this:

```
char arr[99];
```

When supplied as an argument to a function, [it's converted to a pointer to first element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/509868). That is, `scanf` receives a pointer to the first element of the array, just like it expects with a `%[` format specifier.

BTW this is an example of a possible buffer overflow. This example reads one line of text. If the line is long (greater than 98 bytes in my example), `scanf` will cause a buffer overrun. Your example actually does something very similar to [`gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7423691/509868), which is deprecated because of the overruns that it can cause (and which cannot be prevented). Use a bound for your formats, as described e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37577156/509868).

Comment: Crystal ball? `arr` is nowhere declared.

Comment: Yeah, that ball... However, the size of the array was somewhat blurry in the ball, so I just guessed 99.